# CLANG TSAN different result on multiple run same program

Tags: c++, c, clang, thread-sanitizer

I have tried example from CLANG TSAN documentation (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html):

```
#include <pthread.h>
int Global;
void *Thread1(void *x) {
  Global = 42;
  return x;
}
int main() {
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, Thread1, NULL);
  Global = 43;
  pthread_join(t, NULL);
  return Global;
}
```

When I compile and run this example, the result is not uniform. I have to run the program several times ([multiple program run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vn1z.png)), to get correct result. Is it normal behavior?

Comment: Looks like C, why did you tag C++?

Comment: What is "the correct result" given the race condition?  TSAN can only *opportunistically* find data races.

Comment: @pptaszni why doesn't it look like C++?

Comment: Because of `pthread.h` include, C-style thread creation, C-style `void*` args and return types, `*.c` filename. Even though the syntax is correct in both languages.

Comment: I think you just see limitation of thread sanitizer. Your example is to simple to have consistent thread sanitizer result.